# ftp-client works fine. ftp-tls-client fails on one computer and works on another

Tags: windows-7, networking, ftp, ssl, filezilla

Connecting to ftp - from a Windows Server 2012 - it works both secure (-over tls) and unsecure. From a Windows 7 it succeeds unsecure but fails when secure. (Using explicit TLS and passive mode.)

filezilla:

- 234  AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
- Initializing TLS...
- Connection timed out

I've tried *many* things but nothing helps. (I'm also trying this programmatically. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393716/ftp-ssl-fails-after-expecting-tls-negotiation )

The fact that it *does* succeed from one computer proves that the ftp server is fine. And the fact that the Windows 7 computer succeeds *without* tls proves that it's not a NAT/firewall problem (besides, it failed even after disabling firewall etc.). I'm not sure where to start looking. Perhaps a difference between PC Windows and Windows Server?

**EDIT**

The ftp server is on a Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

From the messages your provide it looks like the problem is in the SSL handshake, but for a better analysis more detailed would be necessary. What I've seen so far on problems in this area are:

- Cipher problems. If the FTP server can only do ciphers which are deemed insecure by Windows 7 but are considered secure by Windows 2012 the handshake will fail. But usually you will see a simple fail and not a timeout.
- TLS version problem. I've seen some servers which only can do SSL 3.0 and just close the connection if they get a TLS 1.0 or higher request. This usually does not cause a timeout too.
- Bad load balancer. Older versions of F5 load balancers croaked on a Client Hello which was larger than 255 bytes. They've just dropped the packet which caused a timeout within the handshake at the client. This behaviour would match your problem.

If you need a better analysis please provide a packet dump (wireshark) and describe the network path between the client and the server, that is if there are any middleboxes in between which might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks. Some more info: The server is on Windows Server 2012. And I tried connecting directly to the modem and it made no difference.

Comment: " I tried connecting directly to the modem" - I have no idea of your network architecture and where a modem resides. If you want a better analysis please provide the requested details.